# Android custom dialog skipped frames

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've coded a custom dialog for my application but once I try to open it, I got a lag and the following message is displayed in the `logcat` console:

```
Skipped 31 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

To lower the work, I've moved the `Typeface` loading to an `AsyncTask` but it doesn't solve my problem.

```
  public class CustomDialog
  {
    private Context context = null;
    private Dialog dialog = null;
    private boolean cancelable = true;
    private OnCancelListener cancelListener = null;
    private Typeface latoFont = null;

    private RelativeLayout layout_root = null;
    private TextView text_title = null;
    private TextView text_message = null;
    private LinearLayout layout_buttons = null;

    public CustomDialog(Context context)
    {
      this.context = context;
      this.dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
      this.dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      this.dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
      this.dialog.setCancelable(true);

      layout_root = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layout_root);
      text_title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
      text_message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
      layout_buttons = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layout_buttons);

      // Set background color
      layout_root.setBackgroundColor(FlatUtils.transparentDark(FlatConstants.DOMIANT_COLOR));

      // Set font
      new TypeFaceTask(context, new TextView[]{text_title, text_message}).execute();

      // Attach listener
      layout_root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
          if (view.getId() != R.id.layout_root) return;
          if (cancelable)
          {
            if (cancelListener != null) cancelListener.onCancel();
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
        }
      });
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
      text_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      text_title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
      text_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      text_message.setText(message);
      text_message.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }

    public void addButton(String value, final OnClickListener listener)
    {
      // Create button
      FlatButton button = new FlatButton(context);
      button.setText(value);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(40));
      params.setMargins(0, dpToPx(10), 0, 0);
      layout_buttons.addView(button, params);

      // Set typeface
      if (latoFont != null) button.setTypeface(latoFont);

      // Attach listener
      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
          if (listener != null) listener.onClick(view);
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      });
    }

    public void setCancelable(boolean b)
    {
      cancelable = b;
      dialog.setCancelable(b);
    }

    public void setOnCancelListener(OnCancelListener listener)
    {
      this.cancelListener = listener;
      dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
          cancelListener.onCancel();
        }
      });
    }

    public void show()
    {
      dialog.show();
    }

    public void dismiss()
    {
      dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public interface OnCancelListener {
      public void onCancel();       
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp)
    {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int)(dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f));
    }
  }
```

This is way I create a new dialog:

```
CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(TestActivity.this);
dialog.addButton("Hello 1", null);
dialog.addButton("Hello 2", null);
dialog.addButton("Hello 3", null);
dialog.setTitle("Dummy dialog");
dialog.setMessage("Plop plop");
dialog.show();
```

So my question is: **Is there a way to optimized this code ?**

Comment: Try not calling your dpToPx function to see if that is causing the issue. Also maybe post more code of what you are doing in parallel to creating your dialog.

Comment: Hello. I've tried without `dpToPx` and I got the exact same problem. I've updated my question with the code I use to create a new dialog.

Comment: Updated the answer in light of your emulator use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i think you should try extending the Dialog class instead of wrapping it like this...Your code will be cleaner and more reusable and i think will yield some performance improvement. It wont take you much, most of the code will be the same, but its a general rule of thumb if you want a custom Dialog you should extend the existing elements, similar to when you create an Activity or Fragment you extend them :).

Also i dont know what you are actually doing with your layouts but i see you are getting the screen width and height and then setting margins etc...Such calculations can cause your frames to skip and i would advise you to try making the layout through xml. Trust me, just try playing with layout params through xml and i bet you will get the same result when it comes to margins padings and the overal look, and use the different layout folders(and dimens for margins and paddings for ex) for different screen densities and sizes to achieve the same look across all devices. Not to mention this will perform faster.

Edit 1:

Typefaces wont cause such problems.

***I see you said you are running this on emulator?! Well thats the issue :) i can guarantee that wont happen on a real device***. :))  its  a common thing on the emulator. Always develop on real devices, only they can mimic ***all*** the real problems and bugs you will encounter.

But still listen to the advice's here and follow "best practices" when programming.

Answer (score 1):

1. is it phone or emulator? (try to run on phone)
2. Best practice - to extend DialogFragment(Dialog)
3. Adding buttons from code is strange :) You can declare yor dialog ui using XML layout, inflate it and [set inflated view as content in your dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29)
4. You don't need to load Typeface in asynctask.

So my general suggestion is to learn best practices of creating dialogs.

Comment: I'm using the emulator right now. But I'll try on my phone this evening. 2. I can't as I want it to be compatible with 1.6. 3. OK. 4. Ok

Comment: DialogFragment available in v4 support package so you can use it.